# Populate date dropdown with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, datepicker

I have a dropdown list where the user can choose month/day/year, but to make it a bit quicker for the user i have added in the jquery datepicker, which is working ok except is there a way that once the user has selected a date from the calendar that it automatically populates the drop down fields?
As i have these dropdowns set to import into my database already.

**Current drop downs**

```
<dd>
        <select id="month_of_purchase" name="entry[month_of_purchase]">
            <option value="">Month</option>
            <option value="1">Jan</option>
            <option value="2">Feb</option>
            <option value="3">Mar</option>
            <option value="4">Apr</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">Jun</option>
            <option value="7">Jul</option>
            <option value="8">Aug</option>
            <option value="9">Sep</option>
            <option value="10">Oct</option>
            <option value="11">Nov</option>
            <option value="12">Dec</option>
        </select>
        <select id="day_of_purchase" name="entry[day_of_purchase]">
            <option value="">Day</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
        <select id="year_of_purchase" name="entry[year_of_purchase]">
            <option value="">Year</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
        </select>
        </dd>
```

**Current datepicker**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: is this what you wanted ?http://jsfiddle.net/Un7PG/11/

Comment: is there a way i can have the calendar displayed by clicking an image instead of the input box??

Comment: yeah ,do it this way `<img src="calendar.jpg" id="datepick" />; `. in jquery section `$("#datepick").datepicker();`

Comment: Actually it does'nt matter what kind of element is being used, as far as its attached to trigger `datepicker` over it.

Comment: so it should be something like http://jsfiddle.net/KarinaMcG/Un7PG/13/

Comment: i guess this is what you wanted.http://jsfiddle.net/Un7PG/20/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var mydate= $(this).datepicker("getDate");
            $("#month_of_purchase").val(mydate.getMonth()+1);            
            $("#day_of_purchase").val(mydate.getDate());
            $("#year_of_purchase").val(mydate.getFullYear());
        }
    });
});
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/8SYsN/

Answer (score 1):

try this way

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#tx").datepicker({
    buttonImage: 'http://icongal.com/gallery/image/203336/birthday_rose_for_kdc_kdc_rose_love_flower_valentine_rose.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: 'both'
});

$("#tx").on('change', function () {
    var dt = ($(this).val()).split('/');
    var mon = dt[0];
    var day = dt[1];
    var year = dt[2];
    $('#month_of_purchase').val(mon).attr("selected", "selected");
    $('#day_of_purchase').val(day).attr("selected", "selected");
    $('#year_of_purchase').val(year).attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

});`

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <input type="hidden" id="tx" />
 <select id="month_of_purchase" name="entry[month_of_purchase]">
 <option value="">Month</option>
 <option value="01">Jan</option>
 <option value="02">Feb</option>
 <option value="03">Mar</option>
 <option value="04">Apr</option>
 <option value="05">May</option>
 <option value="06">Jun</option>
 <option value="07">Jul</option>
 <option value="08">Aug</option>
 <option value="09">Sep</option>
 <option value="10">Oct</option>
 <option value="11">Nov</option>
 <option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>
<select id="day_of_purchase" name="entry[day_of_purchase]">
 <option value="">Day</option>
 <option value="01">1</option>
 <option value="02">2</option>
 <option value="03">3</option>
 <option value="04">4</option>
 <option value="05">5</option>
 <option value="06">6</option>
 <option value="07">7</option>
 <option value="08">8</option>
 <option value="09">9</option>
 <option value="10">10</option>
 <option value="11">11</option>
 <option value="12">12</option>
 <option value="13">13</option>
 <option value="14">14</option>
 <option value="15">15</option>
 <option value="16">16</option>
 <option value="17">17</option>
 <option value="18">18</option>
 <option value="19">19</option>
 <option value="20">20</option>
 <option value="21">21</option>
 <option value="22">22</option>
 <option value="23">23</option>
 <option value="24">24</option>
 <option value="25">25</option>
 <option value="26">26</option>
 <option value="27">27</option>
 <option value="28">28</option>
 <option value="29">29</option>
 <option value="30">30</option>
 <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select id="year_of_purchase" name="entry[year_of_purchase]">
 <option value="">Year</option>
 <option value="2011">2011</option>
 <option value="2012">2012</option>
 <option value="2013">2013</option>
 <option value="2014">2014</option>
 <option value="2015">2015</option>
 <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>
```

**LIVE DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Un7PG/21/

**EDIT 1:**

only modification i have done is that, i have converted the date value from `1,2,3...` to `01,02,03......` under value attribute of option tags.

**EDIT 2:**

Trigger a date-picker over a image rather than a traditional text box.

Happy Coding:)